# Function Returning Boolean?

Tags: function, vba

I have simple function in VBA and I would need to check whether or not it has been successfully performed. I do not know VBA much, so I have no idea whether or not its possible. I want to do something like this: `bool X=MyFunction()`.

I am using VBA in the [QTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_QuickTest_Professional) descriptive programming. This does not work:

```
Function A as Boolean
   A=true
End Function
```

It says: `Expected statement`

But I cannot see any return type in my method etc.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
function MyFunction() as Boolean
    .....
    .....
    MyFunction = True 'worked
end function

dim a as boolean = MyFunction()
```

Answer (score 12):

In VBA, you set a function's return value by assigning to a variable with the same name as the function:

```
Function MyFunc() as Boolean
    MyFunc = True
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, I have not written its VBA inside of QTP. When I try this, it says "Statement expected".

Comment: Quick Test Professional from HP.

Comment: Then you're using VBScript, not VBA. VBScript Function Statement documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7hbf8fa

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you may be using VBScript instead of VBA? If that's the case then VBScript doesn't state Type

this will work in VBScript

```
dim test,b
test = 1
b=false
msgbox ("Calling proc before function test=" & test)
msgbox("Calling proc before function b=" & b)
b = A(test)
msgbox ("Calling proc after function test=" & test)
msgbox("Calling proc after function b=" & b)

Function A(test)
test = test +1  
A=true
End Function
```

or in your example

```
Function A()    
A=true
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no real way to check if a function worked in VBA. You must decide for yourself whether your function was successful. For example:

```
Function AFunction() as Boolean
    on error goto 1
    MyFunc = True
    AFunction = True
    Exit Function
    1
    AFunction = False
End Function
```

The above would let you know if the function failed. If it fails, it goes to the label '1' and then returns false, otherwise, it returns true.

If it isn't an 'error' you are looking for, then you must decide if the data returned or supplied is proper. One way of doing this is to return a specific value [error-code] which represents a failure.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have access to your function declaration, you can set a bool return type for it and return true or false depending on the execution.
Once your function returns a bool, your code will work.